# Retrieving the value of select option in Servlets

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I have a select tag in my form which is to be send to Servlet. I have made the contents of the select tag dynamic(it gets values from a table column in DB).

```
Select Branch:-<select>  
            <%  
            while(r.next()){  
    %>  
           <option><%=r.getString("code")%></option>  
            <%  
           }  
r.close();  
s.close();  
con.close();  
    %>  
        </select>
```

('r' is ResultSet) 
My problem is how can i send the value the user has selected from select tag to servlet. For using Request.getparameter("name") I must know the value of option tag. 
I my confused.Please help.. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign a unique name to `select` tag.  `<select name="codeSelect">`

However, this isn't the right way to approach this, perform all the database interaction in Servlet and set appropriate request parameter and forward it to jsp.

Comment: I have added and coded as per second answer but still getting error

Comment: Post the relevant jsp and Servlet code here. Are you using "codeSelect" as the parameter to retrieve.

Comment: <select id="codes">  
        <%  
        while(r.next()){  
        %>  
        <option value="<%=r.getString("code")%>"><%=r.getString("code")%></option>  
        <%  
       }  
       r.close();  
       s.close();  
       con.close();  
       %>  
       </select>

Comment: As i said earlier, assign unique name not id.<select name="codeSelect"> not <select id="codeSelect">
Please post all your code appropriately as well.

Comment: @saumyaRaj: Was this Resolved? If yes, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <select id="codes">  
        <%  
        while(r.next()){  
        %>  
        <option value="<%=r.getString("code")%>"><%=r.getString("code")%></option>  
        <%  
       }  
       r.close();  
       s.close();  
       con.close();  
       %>  
       </select>
```

Now, you can get the value of 'codes'

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /editbranch.jsp at line 77

74:                 <%
75:                 while(r.next()){
76:   %>
77:                <option value="<%=r.getString("code")%>"><%=r.getString("code")%></option>
78:                 <%
79:                }
80:  r.close();